p-convergence vs almost sure convergence of stochastic integral approximating sums
Do we know any specific example when the sequence of Itô-type integral approximating sums
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_{t_{k}}\left(Y_{t_{k+1}\land t}-Y_{t_{k}\land t}\right)$$
doesn't converge almost surely to the stochastic integral $\int_{0}^{T}X_{t}dY_{t}$ (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are good enough to define the integral), the convergence happens only in probability?
I know in general "only" p-limit can be guaranteed and the pathwise calculation of the integral doesn't work anymore, i.e. calculating the limit of the integral approximating sum above we can't expect that the convergence will happen almost surely. But is there any specific example that demonstrates this?
